# Returning elements from an array nest based on criteria

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to search an array for an element (in this case 'electronic'), then return the nested value.

The array that I am working with

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "value" => "0241-6230"
    "type" => "print"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "value" => "2339-1623"
    "type" => "electronic"
  ]
]
```

Below is the code I'm using.

```php
<?php

$this->doi = 'anydoinumber';
$this->client = new Client();
$this->Url = 'https://api.crossref.org/works/:'.$this->doi;
$res = $this->client->get($this->Url);
$decoded_items = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);

if (isset($decoded_items['message']['issn-type'])) {
    $this->issn = '';
} else {
    // no electronic ISSN given
    Log.Alert('No electronic ISSN for :'.$this->Doi);
}
```

The output I'm expecting

```
$this->issn = "2339-1623"
```

Comment: Please can you show the code you have and an example of the output you're expecting?

Comment: Please can you add this to your question rather than put it in the comments :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use laravel collection:

```
collect($array)->where('type', 'electronic')->first();
```

And output is:

```
array:2 [
  "value" => "2339-1623"
  "type" => "electronic"
]
```

Comment: You can read about Laravel collection [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections)

Comment: @user5067291 Maybe you need `get()` instead of `first()`? Please clarify.

Comment: If you need multiple collection objects then use get(). But if you want to get single object from collection then use first().

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple foreach loop that adds matching elements to a results array

```
$filtered = [];
foreach($myarr as $i){
    if($i['type'] == 'searched type')
        $filtered[] = $i;
}
```

or you can break out of the loop when you encounter first element of given type

```
foreach($myarr as $i){
    if($i['type'] == 'searched type')
        return $i; // or $found = $i and then break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP way:

```
$searchingFor = 'electronic';
$filteredArray = array_filter($initialArray, function($v, $k) use ($searchingFor) {
    return $searchingFor === $v['type'];
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

//var_dump($filteredArray);
```

[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Answer (score -1):

You Have To user `foreach` loop

```
$searchterm = 'electronics';
foreach($nested as $key => $value) {
  if($value['type'] == $searchterm) {
    return $value['value'];
    break;
  }
}
```